# Trying to pass variables across sub reports and reports

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I have a report that displays user data and a sub report displaying payment data. I want to tailor my report if there are no payments in the sub report.

The issue I am having is sharing shared variables from the sub report but this only works anything below the sub report. I also tried creating a formula function that calls a count on the amount field and if the count is above 0.00 then it has payments. But For some strange reason crystal report creates 2 of the same pdf's.

How can i find out if there are any records in the sub report and pass that true / false value around the report it inherits?

what i have tried

```
// tried putting this in sub report header but unable to pass it anywhere above the sub report and when adding it to the top level report it duplicates the pages.
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NumberVar RunningTotal;

RunningTotal:= 0;

RunningTotal:= Count({ScheduledComponents_ReportData;1.Amount});
```

thanks....

Answer (score -1):

Shared variable values from a subreport can be used in the main report only in a section BELOW the subreport section.

Comment: I know. I did mention that in my initial question.